# Can we use "would have had" to speculate about past?

Tags: past-tense

Can we use "would have had " to make a guess about the past?

For e.g.

> He would have had those dollars!

(We don't know if he has the dollars but he might have had them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do that! We say that, "He would've had x amount of dollars."

P.S. your usage of e.g. is incorrect. You don't have to say for in front of e.g.